# When I use the SSE to process the communication of server to client. How can I receive the response data in client and don't set the nginx?

Tags: nginx, server-sent-events

When I use the SSE(Server send event) to process the communication of server to client. In order to receive the response data in client immediately.I must set the proxy_buffering to off in nginx , but the performence of nginx will decrease.How can I do it that sure the client can receive the response data immediately and the performence of nginx dosen't need to decrease.Thanks.

I don't want to decrease the performence of nginx and I want to the client can receive the response data immediately also.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.